# Remove /index and Redirect all home pages to one home page

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

Essentially, I have 4 "Home pages" according to Google.
These are:
https://website.com/index https://www.website.com/index https://www.website.com/ https://website.com

I'd like for them all to direct to one, https://www.website.com/

To do this I need to find a way to remove the /index, and direct all the other pages to the one, but I'm having issues setting the .htaccess up correctly. 
Any advice would be appreciated.
How would I go about achieving this effect?

Here is what I've already tried in my .htaccess:

```
`AddHandler application/x-httpd-eig-php52 .php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

Redirect 301 https://website.com/index https://www.website.com/

# Use PHP5.4 as default
#AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php
#Options -Indexes
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|html|htm|xml|txt|css|js|mp4)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536050"
</FilesMatch>`
```

I'm basically just looking to set it up so that the only home page you ever land on is https://www.website.com, rather than 4 possible outcomes.

Comment: You might have more luck getting an answer on https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/apache2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this can do the job

```
RewriteEngine On

# Remove 'index' from link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.website.com/ [R=301,L]

# Add 'www' and preserve all other pages in link
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website.com(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.website.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I tested on [this site](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)

It will all redirect to `https://www.website.com/`, non `www` and with `/index`
and if you have something other than `/index`, for example `/some_page` that will stay

[image]

---

[image]